# mean-before-after imputation in R

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I'm new in R. My question is how to impute missing value using mean of before and after of the missing data point?

example;

using the mean from the upper and lower of each NA as the impute value.

-mean for row number 3 is 38.5

-mean for row number 7 is 32.5

```
age
52.0
27.0
NA
23.0
39.0
32.0
NA
33.0
43.0
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm assuming you have made a mistake when you say that the mean of 27 and 23 is 38.5.

Comment: Yes,the correct mean is 25.0.

Comment: What if an NA is adjacent to another NA?

Answer (score 5):

Here a solution using from `na.locf` from `zoo` package which replaces each NA with the most recent non-NA prior or posterior  to it.

```
0.5*(na.locf(x,fromlast=TRUE) + na.locf(x))
[1] 52.0 27.0 25.0 23.0 39.0 32.0 32.5 33.0 43.0
```

the advantage here if you have more than one consecutive NA.

```
x <- c(52, 27, NA, 23, 39, NA, NA, 33, 43)
0.5*(na.locf(x,fromlast=TRUE) + na.locf(x))
[1] 52 27 25 23 39 36 36 33 43
```

**EDIT**
 `rev` argument is deprecated so I replace it by `fromlast`

Comment: Thank you for your help, i tried using the method above but i did't get the same answer like you did.the imputed value i get is the value before the NA, not the mean before and after the NA's.how do i fix this?.thanks again.

Comment: If we have some "NA" consecutively, for example (52,27,NA,NA,23,NA,NA,NA, 33,43), what can we do?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for Moving Average Imputation - you can use the **na_ma** function of **imputeTS** for this.

```
library(imputeTS)
x <- c(52, 27, NA, 23, 39, NA, NA, 33, 43)
na_ma(x, k=1, weighting = "simple")
```

> [1] 52.00000 27.00000 25.00000 23.00000 39.00000 31.66667 38.33333
> 33.00000 43.00000

This produces exactly the required result.
With the **k** parameter you specify how many neighbors on each side are taken into account for the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a basic manual approach you can take:

```
age <- c(52, 27, NA, 23, 39, 32, NA, 33, 43)
age[is.na(age)] <- rowMeans(cbind(age[which(is.na(age))-1], 
                                  age[which(is.na(age))+1]))
age
# [1] 52.0 27.0 25.0 23.0 39.0 32.0 32.5 33.0 43.0
```

Or, since you seem to have a single column `data.frame`:

```
mydf <- data.frame(age = c(52, 27, NA, 23, 39, 32, NA, 33, 43))

mydf[is.na(mydf$age), ] <- rowMeans(
  cbind(mydf$age[which(is.na(mydf$age))-1],
        mydf$age[which(is.na(mydf$age))+1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an other way:

```
age <- c(52, 27, NA, 23, 39, 32, NA, 33, 43)
age[is.na(age)] <- apply(sapply(which(is.na(age)), "+", c(-1, 1)), 2, 
                         function(x) mean(age[x]))
age
## [1] 52.0 27.0 25.0 23.0 39.0 32.0 32.5 33.0 43.0
```